# Me gustaría saber para que funciona usar .length -1 en un array, debido a que me funciono usarlo pero no se que es lo que hace

Tags: c#

[image: código usado para la solución del problema]

se usa el metodo numeros.Length -1; para solucionar el codigo pero no se como se usa bien -1 dentro de un array

```
Console.WriteLine("Digite el total de números a usar:");
int totalNumeros = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] numeros = new int[totalNumeros);

int resultadoMayor = numeros.Length -1; //recorre el array
int resultadoMenor = numeros.Length -1;

for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++){

    Console.WriteLine("Digite el valor del número: " + i);
    numeros[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (numeros[i] > reaultadoMayor){
        resultadoMayor = numeros[i];
    }

    if (numeros[i] < reaultadoMenor){
        resultadoMenor = numeros[i];
    }
}

Console.WritLine($"Del array presentado, el número menor es {resultadoMenor} y el mayor es {resultadoMayor}");
```

Comment: los  arreglos empiezan en 0 como primera posicion, pero length devuelve el numero de elementos. ejemplo  `a = [1,2,3]; a.length` devolvera 3 pero si haces `a[3]` no existe dado que el primer elemento no es 1 si no 0... por eso siempre se le resta 1 ahora si `a[2]` sera igual a 3;

Comment: Si esto anda, es de casualidad... tal vez por los numeros que hay.. pero en realidad, no deberia andar nunca... mira el comentario de arriba...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Answer (score 0):

Analicemos tu código, que por cierto me has obligado a reescribir por poner una imagen en lugar de una captura de texto del código

```
//Pides el total de números
Console.WriteLine("Ponga el total de números");

//almacenas eses total en la variable totalNumeros
int totalNumeros = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

//creas un array de numeros enteros con el límite del número anterior
//al crear un array sin dar valores se igualan dichos valores a cero
int[] numeros = new int[totalNumeros);
        //tu array sería equivalente a:
        numeros[0] = 0;
        numeros[1] = 0;
        numeros[2] = 0;
        numeros[3] = 0;
        numeros[4] = 0;
        numeros[5] = 0;
        numeros[6] = 0;
        ...

//tomas el último valor del array, que es 0, y lo guardas en la variable resultadoMayor
//Como te han explicado, el último valor del array será su dimensión menos 1, dado que los array empiezan en 0
//Si un array tiene 5 valores (array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4]), él último valor del array será array[4] o sea, array.Length, que vale 5, menos 1
int resultadoMayor = numeros.Length -1;

//tomas el último valor del array, que es 0,dado que no le has dado valor, y lo guardas en la variable resultadoMenor
int resultadoMenor = numeros.Length -1;

//creas un bucle for con el límite del tamaño del array números
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++){

    //pides los valores del array por cada iteración del bucle
    Console.WriteLine("Ponga el número: " + i);

    //recoges el valor en el lugar correspondiente del array al índice del bucle
    numeros[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    //creas un condicionante que evalúa si el número recogido es mayor que el valor almacenado en la variable resultadoMayor
    //sabemos que resultadoMayor vale 0
    //si se introduce otro cero, como no es mayor, no entrará en el if, y resultadoMayor se quedará con el 0
    //si se introduce otro número, como es mayor que cero entrará en el if
    if (numeros[i] > reaultadoMayor){
        //resultadoMayor tomará el número introducido por teclado
        resultadoMayor = numeros[i];
    }

    //este if solo llegará a funcionar si se introducen números negativos, pues el número almacenado en resultadoMenor es un 0, y como sabemos, ningún número es menor que cero salvo los negativos
    if (numeros[i] < reaultadoMenor){
        resultadoMenor = numeros[i];
    }
}
```

El error que observo en tu código, es tomar como referencia un valor artificial, pues no sabemos si el usuario llegaría o no a introducir un cero entre los números elegidos, y por tanto, lo introduzca o no, el número menor siempre será cero independientemente de que sea introducido o no por el usuario.

Sería recomendado que tanto númeroMayor como númeroMenor, los tomaras en la primera iteración del bucle

```
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++){

    Console.WriteLine("Ponga el número: " + i);

    numeros[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (i == 0){
        numeroMayor = numeros[i];
        numeroMenor = numeros[i];
    }

    if (numeros[i] > resultadoMayor){
        resultadoMayor = numeros[i];
    }

    if (numeros[i] < resultadoMenor){
        resultadoMenor = numeros[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Falta una comilla en ambos fragmentos

Comment: Gracias @Mateo, la verdad es que no he llegado a probar el código. Escribí la respuesta directamente aquí. Creo que ya las he puesto. Un saludo